# tkinter передать данные во фрейм

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = Tk()
root.title('програмка')
root.geometry('600x400+1000+300')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.config(bg='green')


btn = Button(root, text='кнопка', font='Tahoma', command = dms)
btn.configure(width='30', height='5')
btn.pack()

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=50, height=10)
txt.pack()

def dms():
    def splitfile(file_name, sep):
        file = open(file_name, 'r')
        text = file.read()
        file.close()
        text = text.split(sep)
        return text

    list1 = splitfile('1.txt', '\n')
    list2 = splitfile('2.txt', '\n')
    result = list(set(list1) - set(list2))

    file = open('res.txt', 'w')
    file.write('\n'.join(result))
    file.close()

    f = open('res.txt', 'r')
    t = f.read()
    txt.insert(1.0, t)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
f = open('res.txt', 'r')
t = f.read()
Label(topframe, text="Date").pack()
e1 = Entry(topframe)
e1.insert(0, t)
e1.pack()
```

Comment: file.insert(open('res.txt', 'chars', 'r').read())
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: @Jimmy поправил

Comment: f = open('res.txt', 'r', 'chars')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: @Jimmy, insert(0, t)

Comment: спасибо, но ошибка закралась видимо в другом месте, сейчас выдаёт "_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"", хотя в файле есть данные

Comment: добавил в пример весь код скрипта

Comment: @Jimmy, ну правильно ведь в начале вы написали Entry а сейчас пытаетесь scrolledtext.ScrolledText

Comment: @Jimmy, тогда нужно insert(1.0, t). И проверьте программу так как вы перезаписываете файл res.txt

Comment: программа работает корректно, файл res.txt записывается, но в ScrolledText содержимое не переносится, а что значит запись insert(1.0, t), что такое "1.0"?

Comment: @Jimmy, номер строки и номер позиции

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108093/discussion-between-jimmy-and-).